# Back button from my app goes to home screen rather than previous app

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to debug an issue and I'm not sure what is going on.

My application is launched from application A (this is not mine, someone else's, so I don't have any source code)

When I click the back button on my application, I land on the Android home screen rather than going to the application that launch me. I checked all the flags in the intent that I receive, and everything is turned off.

Now if I launch my application from any other application, then pressing the back button goes back to the application that launch me.

I'm not sure how to debug this issue. Any ideas?

Comment: what makes you think its your problem?

Comment: Have you check your AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application A might call `finish()` once the `Intent` is sent to start your `Activity`. Then the `Activity` in application A that started the `Intent` to launch your `Activity` will go through `onDestroy()` and will be removed from the backstack, so when you press the back key you will go to the home screen if the `Activity` in Application A was the first `Activity` launched by Application A